# Storing Array values to integer

Tags: node.js, postgresql

trying to store array values in integer . this is my code . is it wrong?

```
db.query('INSERT INTO users(name,student_id) VALUES($1,ARRAY["$2","$3"]::INTEGER[]) RETURNING *', [data.name, data.id])
.then(function(user) { })
.catch(function(err) {
    return callback(null, err);
})
```

but i am getting this error

```
{
 "name": "error",
 "length": 102,
 "severity": "ERROR",
 "code": "42703",
 "position": "70",
 "file": "parse_relation.c",
 "line": "3090",
 "routine": "errorMissingColumn"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`42703` means `undefined_column` - this happens, because you use double quotes around `"$2","$3"` and double quotes are identifying db objects (in this part of the query - columns). Remove them to be:

```
db.query('INSERT INTO users(name,student_id) VALUES($1,ARRAY[$2,$3]::INTEGER[]) RETURNING *', [data.name, data.id])
.then(function(user) { })
.catch(function(err) {
    return callback(null, err);
})
```

Comment: yes i removed double quotes and i am getting like this `You will need to rewrite or cast the expression`

Comment: it means that ether `$1` is of different data type then "name "column, or "student_id" column is not of integer[] data type. but that is totally different question

Comment: name column is character , but student_id is integer. i need to store multiple id's to student_id column so do you have any idea on Foreign key constraint for array-field ?

Comment: you can't put integer[] into integer. It's not about FK

Comment: ok actually i would like to store multiple id's to the student_id column of users table. but it has the reference of departments table _id which is declared by int type so if you have any idea please suggest me

Comment: you ask a question (quote clear one) and get the answer, which solves the problem. If you have another question, ask it. please don't chat in comments